# Angular2 redirecting to root folder

Tags: apache, angular, typescript, server, localhost

I am new to Angular 2 and trying to create my first application. I am following  [this](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/03/25/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-1-your-first-component/) tutorial to develop first application. I created application as suggested and my main files are:
**systemjs.config.js**

```js
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**main.ts**

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And I am initializing angular from following code in index.html

```html
 <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      // import the 'app' module to boostrap the application
      System.import('app')
            .catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

My project folder name is myangular. So, My request is http://localhost/myangular/index.html

**Problem**

> As you can see in below image, Third request moved to root of localhost(Apache server). Here dashboard of default page of Apache. This result in error.

[image]

Please help me where I am missing configuration.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is most likely a server issue, so you'd probably get more help if you add the tag for it as well.

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/myangular">` as first child in `<head>` of your `idnex.html`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed by changing `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/myangular/">` (index.html). In my case, I have to keep the "/" after the folder name.